# Location Manager inside Async Task from Service

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, locationmanager

I have a service which checks a Database through a period of time to check if there is a valid requirement for the GPS. If there is a usage, it then starts the GPS locationupdates. I tried using a different thread but it would cause the App to hang. I found the App performed better with the do in background.

I keep getting the following error

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called
>   Looper.prepare().

I try to use Looper but I just for some reason just can't seem to find the right way to implement it. I need a hand getting to the PingListener which will not run, I did remove the error by adding in

`Looper.prepare();`

before the While loop in gpsPlotter.

Please ignore all the logging and some garbage variables I left which I've left in there as I like to trace everything while coding.

```
public class PingListener implements LocationListener{
    public void onLocationChanged(Location pointer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String lat = String.valueOf(pointer.getLatitude());
        String longi = String.valueOf(pointer.getLongitude());
        new pingThread().execute(lat, longi);
        Log.d("Updating", "Sending Updates");

    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}


private class pingThread extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BeaconHandler db = new BeaconHandler(Ping.this);
        List<Beacon> beacons = db.getAllBeacons();

        int activecheck = 0;
        for(Beacon bn : beacons){
            activecheck = activecheck + bn.getStatus();
        }
        Log.d("Active Result", String.valueOf(activecheck));
        String ger = "";
        String postresponse = "";

          try{

            HttpClient retCode = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost retEmail = new HttpPost("http://www.site.com/tracker/return.php");

            List<NameValuePair> createValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            createValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vert", args[0]));
            createValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("horz", args[1]));
            createValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "2"));

            retEmail.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(createValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            ResponseHandler<String> createresponseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            postresponse = retCode.execute(retEmail, createresponseHandler);

            ger = "Network Details\nLat:" + args[0] + "\nLong:" + args[1];
            Log.d("Sent: ", ger);
          }
          catch(Exception e){
              Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
              Log.getStackTraceString(e);
          }

        return ger;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String value){


    }

}


private class gpsPlotter extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int updateset = 0;
                    //Looper.prepare();
        while(true){
            try{
                BeaconHandler dbg = new BeaconHandler(Ping.this);
                List<Beacon> beacons = dbg.getAllBeacons();
                int activecheck = 0;
                for(Beacon bn : beacons){
                    activecheck = activecheck + bn.getStatus();
                }
                //db.close();
                if(activecheck > 0 && updateset == 0){
                    pinger.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 600, 0, reciever);
                    updateset = 1;
                    Log.d("GPS RESET", "Listener Set");
                }
                else if(activecheck == 0 && updateset == 1){
                    pinger.removeUpdates(reciever);
                    updateset = 0;
                    Log.d("GPS RESET", "Listener Removed");
                }
                else{
                    Log.d("GPS RESET", "No Modifications");
                }
                Thread.sleep(20000);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("GPS RESET ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IntentService` instead of `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Using the Intent Service turns out to be a better process than doinbackground. This answer did lack some vital information which could have helped me to a quicker resolution. I did change my methodology and using the reference provided below switched to a intent service.

http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/04/working-with-services-in-android-intentservice/

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a Looper.loop() after the while loop

```
private class gpsPlotter extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int updateset = 0;
                Looper.prepare();
    while(true){
        try{
            BeaconHandler dbg = new BeaconHandler(Ping.this);
            List<Beacon> beacons = dbg.getAllBeacons();
            int activecheck = 0;
            for(Beacon bn : beacons){
                activecheck = activecheck + bn.getStatus();
            }
            //db.close();
            if(activecheck > 0 && updateset == 0){
                pinger.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 600, 0, reciever);
                updateset = 1;
                Log.d("GPS RESET", "Listener Set");
            }
            else if(activecheck == 0 && updateset == 1){
                pinger.removeUpdates(reciever);
                updateset = 0;
                Log.d("GPS RESET", "Listener Removed");
            }
            else{
                Log.d("GPS RESET", "No Modifications");
            }
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("GPS RESET ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    Looper.loop();
}
```

}

Comment: That won't work because I'm dealing with a true in my While loop. I now see where some of my problem is coming from.

Comment: You have to put a break somewhere in your loop, but you still need Looper.loop() in the end;